# transform sql to linq with join, group-by and where

Tags: c#, linq, join, group-by, aggregate

I have the following sql, which I want to convert to linq

```
SELECT Contrato.finca, SUM(Pago.Importe_subtotal)
FROM Pago, Contrato
WHERE Pago.Contrato = Contrato.ID AND Pago.pagado = 1
GROUP BY Contrato.finca
ORDER BY 2 DESC
GO
```

What I have now in linq is the following, but the group by doesn't work.

```
var x = from contrato in ctx.Contratos 
        join pago in ctx.Pagos
        on contrato.ID equals pago.Contrato 
        where pago.pagado == true 
        group contrato by contrato.finca
        select contrato.Finca1;
```

Comment: Is there a need for the join when using Linq? If your entity model is set up properly the related entity should be a property. What does your database schema look like?

Comment: Doesn't work... _what_ is not working about it?

Comment: It is a property. It's in the Finca1

Comment: Is Pago a property of Contrato in your entity model?

Comment: Can you post a diagram of your database model so I can see how the items are related?

Comment: No, Contrato is a property from pago and Contrato has a property pagos (from the foreign key constraint?)

Comment: the diagram : http://picpaste.com/diagramm-e7bXQWnO.png

Comment: both answers work now for me and I can only accept one answer :( since I don't understand (yet) the syntax of slick86's answer, I accept the answer of Vlad. I think, I need to learn a lot about linq. Thank you very much!

Comment: Please also let me know if the one I just revised works. It eliminates the unneeded join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think this should work:

```
ctx.Pagos.Where(m=>m.pagado==true).GroupBy(m=>m.Contrato.finca) 
    .Select(m=> new { Id= m.Key, Val= m.Sum(n => n.Importe_subtotal)})
```

Comment: I have added a ")" to close the Sum. This syntax is completely new to me. Do you have any link, on how to use it? I get the following error: The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Join<TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TOuter>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>, System.Func<TOuter,TKey>, System.Func<TInner,TKey>, System.Func<TOuter,TInner,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: This is the method syntax. I think it is much easier to read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669071.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var x = from contrato in ctx.Contratos 
        join pago in ctx.Pagos
        on contrato.ID equals pago.Contrato 
        where pago.pagado == true 
        group new {contrato, pago} by contrato.finca into g
        select new {
            key = g.Key, 
            sum = g.Sum(p => p.pago.Importe_subtotal)
        };
```

Comment: I get the following error: Error 1 'System.Linq.IGrouping<int,Ejercicio2.Contrato>' does not contain a definition for 'Finca1' and no extension method 'Finca1' - the g shows no properties in intellisence

Comment: You have in your code Finca1 that is why I put Finca1, but I also see you have finca.  I don't know your Model Type, I just did based on what I saw in your code.  But in your initial code you were using into statement.  Also I added SUM aggregation, since you have it in your initial query.

Comment: now I get the error Identifier expected; 'new' is a keyword. Finca1 was autogenerated by the foreign key constraint. finca is the name of the id of the finca

Comment: I fixed that, try again.  The only thing is I am not sure is Finca1 or Finca, since I see in your query you have Finca, but in your LINQ you have Finca1.

Comment: still getting the error: Identifier expected; 'new' is a keyword